# Specifying output location of PHP queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a small PHP project as an introduction to the language and am having trouble with formatting database query results. My PHP functions are working correctly, but the results are being displayed above all of the HMTL, like this: [image: here]

Here's my code, all in a file called index.php. Could somebody point out where I'm going wrong? I want it to display right below the navigation bar (Home, Friend List, etc), How do I specify exactly where I want he PHP to appear in the HTML?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BumpIt</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>



    <!-- Login PHP -->
    <?php
    ini_set("display_errors", true);

    session_start();

    // Store username and password in session variables
    if (isset($_POST['signin_user']))
    {
      $_SESSION['signin_user']=$_POST['signin_user'];
      $_SESSION['signin_pass']=$_POST['signin_pass'];

    }


    // Reset username and pass to that of the session variables
    $signin_user = $_SESSION['signin_user'];
    $signin_pass = $_SESSION['signin_pass'];
    $isSigningIn = $_POST['isSigningIn'];




    // Connect to the database, check if error happens
    $conn = pg_connect(Redacted*);
    $_SESSION['conn'] = $conn;
    if (!$conn) {
      echo "Connection failed";
    exit;
  }


/**************************************************************
**************************************************************
*****************    FUNCTIONS     ***************************
**************************************************************
***************************************************************/


    // Load Friend List function
    if($_GET['friendList']){friendList();}

    function friendList(){
      $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
      $query = sprintf("SELECT username FROM (SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = $userID) AS currFriends, users WHERE friend_id = user_id;");
      $result = pg_query($_SESSION['conn'], $query);

      echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>\n";
      echo "<caption>Friend List</caption>\n";
      while ($line=pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
          echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
      }
      echo "</table>\n";
    }


    // LOGIC NOT WORKING RIGHT YET (DISPLAYING MULTIPLES OF SAME NAME)
    // Find Friends function
    if($_POST['search']){searchForFriends();}

    function searchForFriends() {
      $search = $_POST['search'];
      $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
      $query = sprintf("SELECT userName FROM (SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = $userID) AS currFriends, users WHERE friend_id <> users.user_id AND userName ILIKE ( '%%' || "."'".$search."'"." || '%%');");
      echo "DEBUG PURPOSES-> SEARCHFORFRIENDS QUERY IS: ".$query;
      $result = pg_query($_SESSION['conn'], $query);

      echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>\n";
      echo "<caption>Users</caption>\n";
      while ($line=pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
          echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
         echo "\t</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";

    }

?>










    <img class="header-logo" src="img/bumpit.png"></img>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="friendList" href="index.php?friendList=true">Friend List</a></li>
            <li>
              <a id="logoutBtn" href="index.php?logoutBtn=true">Logout</a>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Search bar -->
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="index.php?search=true" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              <input name="isSigningIn" type="hidden" value="1">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>


        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->





      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

      <!-- Main content -->

      <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">

<!-- WE WANT THE FRIENDS LIST HERE -->
         </div>
       </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: `<!-- WE WANT THE FRIENDS LIST HERE --> if($_GET['friendList']){friendList();}`

Comment: Also `session_start()` placed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to move this:

```
// Load Friend List function
if($_GET['friendList']){friendList();}
```

To where you want the friendList printed:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">

     <!-- WE WANT THE FRIENDS LIST HERE -->
     <?php
         // Load Friend List function
         if (isset($_GET['friendList'])) { friendList(); }
     ?>
     </div>
   </div><!-- /.container -->
```

You have to add it in `<?php ?>` and I have also altered `if` statement so it does not throw a notice if `friendList` wouldn't be set.